# Подключение файлов

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно организовать такой функционал?
Нужно чтобы на странице отображался селект с файлами из директории и при выборе пользователем подключался выбранный фаил!

Comment: Что значит подключался? Куда подключался?

Comment: это точно что "фаил" ...

Comment: ну include или require в сценарий!

Comment: Попробуйте четко и ясно сформулировать что вам нужно.

Comment: нужно что бы пользователь имел возможность подключить нужный файл из директории к сценарию!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так.

```
<?php

$fdir = './';

if(! is_dir($fdir))
    exit('Неверно задана директория.');

if(!empty($_GET['file'])){
    $file = trim($_GET['file']);
    $file = basename($file);
    $f    = end(explode('/', $file));       
    if (substr($file, 0, 1) == '.'){
        print 'Чтение данных файлов запрещено.';    
    }elseif(file_exists($file) && is_readable($file)){
        //тут из вашей задачи не понятно, подключить типа require/include, или все же предоставить на чтение. будем думать что на чтение.
        print htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file)); //
        // или include($file);

    }else{
        print 'Файл не найден.';
    }
    print "<br />";     
}

$dir = opendir($fdir);
while($file = readdir($dir)){
    if( is_file($file) && substr($file, 0, 1) != '.' ) //сразу же отрубим файлы типа .htpasswd, .htaccess, и ..
        print "<a href='?file={$fdir}{$file}'>$file</a><br />"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: не знаю в чем проблема но ссылка на файлы не выводятся! директорию находит ошибок не выдает, а на экране ничего нет!

Comment: может еще кто нибудь поможет!пожалуйста)))

Comment: там файлы-то есть? кстати какая версия php?